# locally free resolution for computation of Ext sheaves in Hartshorne Proposition 6.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

I have a question about Proposition 6.5., Chap III (on page 234) from Hartshorne's
Algebraic Geometry.
The statement is:

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X$ be ringed space. Suppose there is an exact sequence

$$ ... \to \mathcal{L}_1 \to \mathcal{L}_0 \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$$

in $\mathcal{Mod}(X)$, the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules, where
the $\mathcal{L}_i$ are locally free sheaves of finite rank (in this case
we say $\mathcal{L}_{\bullet}$. is a locally free resolution of $\mathcal{F}$).
Then for any $\mathcal{G} \in \mathcal{Mod}(X)$
we have

$$   \mathcal{Ext}^i(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})  \cong
h^i(\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{L}_{\bullet}, \mathcal{G})).     $$

here the $\mathcal{Ext}^i(\mathcal{F}, -)$ are the right derived functors of
$\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{F}, -)$ and the right hand side the cohomology sheaves of complex $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{L}_{\bullet}, \mathcal{G})$.

The proof says that both sides are $\delta$-functors in $\mathcal{G}$ from
$\mathcal{Mod}(X)$ to $\mathcal{Mod}(X)$. For $i = 0$
they are equal, because then $\mathcal{Hom}(-,\mathcal{G})$ is contravariant
and left exact.
Both sides vanish for $i > 0$ when is $\mathcal{F}$ injective, because then
$\mathcal{Hom}(-,\mathcal{G})$ is exact.
So by (1.3A) they are equal.

**Theorem 1.3A.** on page 206 states: Let $T = (T^i)_{i \ge 0}$ be a
covariant $\delta$-functor
from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ ($\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ are
abelian categories). If
$T^i$ is effaceable for each $i > 0$, then $T$ is universal.
The definitions of *effaceable* and *universal $\delta$-functor* can be
looked up on the sage page.

My question is: Why is it neccessary for the proof to assume that
the  $\mathcal{L}_i$ are *locally free*? I see no reason why the same proof
shouldn't go through verbatim if we start with an arbitrary resolution
of $\mathcal{F}$, ie a family $(\mathcal{A}_i)_{i \ge 0}$ in
$\mathcal{Mod}(X)$ there is an exact sequence
$... \to \mathcal{A}_1 \to \mathcal{A}_0 \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$ of
$\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: If an arbitrary resolution would work then you might as well take the trivial resolution $0 \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$ thus producing trivial Ext always. Which surely isn't desirable. :-)

Comment: You have some typos/errors in here which might be contributing to your confusion. First, these are $\delta$-functors in $G$ from $Mod(X)$ to $Mod(X)$; next, these vanish for $i>0$ and $G$ injective.

Comment: It looks like this question has been discussed on here before: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162966/where-we-use-assumption-that-resolution-is-locally-free-hartshorne-iii-6-5?rq=1). Does this resolve your question?

Comment: yeah, thanks!!!